# Dynamics 365 CRM and Outlook App Lookup issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, crm-outlook-client

On the Lookup record, I can’t select  Contact entity as it is missing from the drop down.
[image: Lookup view with no Contact entity]

Sorry for the brief question my boss has provided only this much information and my CRM user is not setup for email etc so cannot test it out on outlook myself.

If you guys need more details let me know, I will try to get it.
Just want to know why Contact is not showing up for selection.

Comment: Guess: you want to know why contact is not showing there?

Answer (score 0):

Once the users outlook was re-installed(office re-install). this problem went away. Don't know why